# Is the React Native Image component affected by the libwebp vulnerability (CVE-2023-4863)?

Tags: react-native, security, webp

On September 11th, 2023, a vulnerability was assigned CVE-2023-4863, the bug was found to be in the WebP Codec image rendering library (libwebp). The WebP Codec library is a library used to encode and decode images in WebP format, and is not unique to Chrome but rather utilized by Chromium and incorporated in many other applications.

I know that expo-image was affected by it, and the Expo team has released a fix: https://blog.expo.dev/fix-for-cve-2023-4863-in-expo-image-1-3-4-59c04c40758e

Does anyone know if the built in Image component in React Native is affected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out React-Native Image is affected by the libwebp vulnerability, as it uses a library called [Fresco](https://frescolib.org/), which is maintained by Meta. Fresco in turn uses libwebp, Fresco recently [bumped](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/commit/58af8bcf5c27ad63f8991536f8acabf4fe258c3c) their libwebp version to [1.3.2](https://github.com/webmproject/libwebp/releases/tag/v1.3.2) which contains a fix for the vulnerability.
However, React-Native have not upgraded their Fresco version to 3.1.1, which means it's still vulnerable, I have reported this to Meta.